# Data structure keeping the order of ManyToMany items

Tags: mysql, sql, django, database, doctrine

For example,

There are two lines and a few stations.

```
Line X 
Station A - Station B - Station C - Station D

Line Y
Station E - Station F - Station B - Station G
```

Line X and Y are crossing at Station B

So my tables are like this below

Line Table

```
1 X  "LineX"
2 Y  "LineY"
```

Station Table

```
1 A X
2 B X,Y
3 C X
4 D X
5 E Y
6 F Y
7 G Y
```

Models are like this (This is django but using doctrine are almost same.)

```
class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    lines = models.ManyToManyField(Line)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In this case, you can get the stations of LineX easily.

`SELECT from station table where line (which include) Y`

`return A,B,C,D`

However for `LineY`

it returns `B`,`E`,`F`,`G`

but `B` is not the top.

It's third station.

I think I should add some column to maintain the order of each lines.

What is the best practice for structure keeping the order of manytomany items?

I am familliar with Doctorine2 and django models.

I would appreciate any help of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: this answer considers the data structure in the DB only, and does not address django.

Perhaps you could implement a Line_Order table with foreign keys to the line, and the stations. I'd also have a direction tag (as I assume your lines are bi-directional and not circular)

E.g.

```
    Line_id    Station_id    Direction
1   1          1             Line X Eastbound
2   1          2             Line X Eastbound
...
5   1          4             Line X Westbound
...
10  2          5             Line Y Northbound
11  2          6             Line Y Northbound
12  2          2             Line Y Northbound
13  2          7             Line Y Northbound
...
```

And then to be honest, I'd drop the Line column entirely from the stations table.

The above structure is brittle to changes. If your train lines are likely to be modified, then you may alternatively wish to consider a "Next station" table analogous to a linked list. Your table could list the line_id, the station_id, the next station_id and the previous station_id. The direction of travel may or may not be required depending on your implementation.